# How to solve a probability intersection problem without multiplying

Tags: probability

I'm doing some probability homework (It's the beginning of the semester, so it's pretty basic stuff). I need to find $P(A∩B)$. However, for some reason, neither my textbook (*Probability and Statistical Inference* by Hogg) or my prof have taught that $P(A∩B)=P(A)P(B)$, which is common sense to me. All I've got is $P(A')$, $P(B')$ and $P(A'∩B')$. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ isn’t true in general. The two events must be independent. Try looking at $P((A\cap B)')$.

Comment: @amd By De Morgan's law, $P((A∩B)')=P(A')∪P(B')$ (please correct me if I'm wrong.) How can I possibly find such a value?

Comment: @Jakedesnake: Close, but not quite. Rather, $P\bigl((A\cap B)'\bigr)=P(A'\cup B').$

Comment: @CameronBuie Interesting! That would give me the solution I need! By why is that? Is it just a misinterpretation of De Morgan's law that I made?

Comment: By DeMorgan's Laws, $(A\cap B)'=A'\cup B'.$

Comment: Or were you asking why my *answer* is true?

Comment: @CameronBuie From what I gathered from your comment, De Morgan's law state that $P((A∩B)')=P(A'∪B')$ and not $P((A∩B)')=P(A')∪P(B')$ as I thought

Comment: Well, what would a union of two real numbers even mean?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$P(X\cup Y)=P(X)+P(Y)-P(X\cap Y).$$

Answer (score 0):

The probability of the intersection of two events is only the product of their individual probabilities if the events are independent.

$P(A \bigcap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\bigcup B) $